# Recursively copy a set of files from one directory to another in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to copy all `*.csproj.user` files recursively from `C:\Code\Trunk` to `C:\Code\F2`.

For example:

`C:\Code\Trunk\SomeProject\Blah\Blah.csproj.user`

Would get copied to:

`C:\Code\F2\SomeProject\Blah\Blah.csproj.user`

My current attempt is:

> Copy-Item C:\Code\Trunk -Filter *.csproj.user -Destination
>   C:\Code\F2 -Recurse -WhatIf

However I get:

> What if: Performing operation "Copy Directory" on Target "Item:
>   C:\Code\Trunk Destination: C:\Code\F2\Trunk".

First, it wants to put them all in a new folder called `F2\Trunk` which is wrong.  Second, it doesn't list any of the files.  There should be about 10 files to be copied over.

What's the correct syntax for the command?  Thanks!

**Update:**

Okay, it seems to have something to do with the fact that `C:\Code\F2` already exists.  If I try copying the files over to a destination that does *not* exist, it works.

I want to *overwrite* any existing `.csproj.user` files in the destination.

Comment: The part about it creating a new folder is a bug which has been documented [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/809855/subfolder-bug-with-command-copy-item-c-folder-c-folder2-recurse-when-done-more-times).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seen this before, and I don't know why PowerShell can't seem to get it right (IMHO). What I would do is more cumbersome but it works.

```
$Source = 'C:\Code\Trunk'
$Files = '*.csproj.user'
$Dest = 'C:\Code\F2'
Get-ChildItem $Source -Filter $Files -Recurse | ForEach{
    $Path = ($_.DirectoryName + "\") -Replace [Regex]::Escape($Source), $Dest
    If(!(Test-Path $Path)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Path -Force | Out-Null
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $Path -Force
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove the whole regex thing if you use the parameter `-LiteralPath` for the `Copy-Item` command

Comment: This only seems to copy one file from each subfolder

Answer (score 97):

You guys are making this hideously complicated, when it's really simple:

```
Copy-Item C:\Code\Trunk -Filter *.csproj.user -Destination C:\Code\F2 -Recurse
```

Will copy the **Directory**, creating a "Trunk" directory in F2. If you want to avoid creating the top-level Trunk folder, you have to stop telling PowerShell to copy it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Code\Trunk | Copy-Item -Destination C:\Code\F2 -Recurse -filter *.csproj.user
```

Comment: No one would've dreamed that the first way was "telling" it to copy the folder, since "copy" is an alias to "copy-item", and "copy" in DOS didn't work that way, if I'm not mistaken.  Hence the confusion and complication many have had with this.

Comment: For me, this flattens everything and copies the lot into one folder

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately, Copy-Item has a, uhm, bug (which has been enshrined to avoid "breaking" old scripts): If you want to create the destination directory, you can use the first command (just copy-item), if it already exists, that's when you need the second syntax.

Comment: For future reference: a [Rejected Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26200235) titled "The first form works without copying the root source folder, just add "\*" to it and it will only copy items inside of it" proposed changing the last line of code to `Copy-Item C:\Code\Trunk\* -Filter *.csproj.user -Destination C:\Code\F2 -Recurse
`: _This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer._

Comment: `-Filter` only supports one filter, so if you want multiple file extensions this doesn't work (as a single command). And while `-Include` supports mutiple patterns, it doesn't seem to work with `-Recurse`.

Comment: @yoyo Yeah, we're using -filter only because copying one specific extension was the original request ...

Answer (score 28):

While the most voted answer is perfectly valid for single file types, if you need to copy multiple file types there is a more useful functionality called robocopy exactly for this purpose with simpler usage

```
robocopy C:\Code\Trunk C:\Code\F2 *.cs *.xaml *.csproj *.appxmanifest /s
```

Comment: I had to use Robocopy, because Copy-Item errored on longer file paths

Answer (score 5):

I tried Jaykul answer and it did not work for me. I had to change it as below to get it to work.  I also created the C:\Code\F2 folder before it worked.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Code\Trunk -Recurse -filter *.csproj.user | Copy -Destination C:\Code\F2
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. But had to add the hyphen character before 'Recurse'

Comment: This one did **not** recreate the source folder structure in the destination folder for me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 looked good, and I changed to `Move-Item` for my purposes.  However I found that in each folder it recursively went through, it only moved the first file.  Below is my complete script which also includes some conversion of doc files to pdf's:

```
$Source = 'C:\Users\sgrody\Desktop\NSPM-Vol1'
$MoveFiles = '*.PDF'
$Dest = 'C:\Users\sgrody\Desktop\MedPassPDF'
$Folders = Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory -Recurse 


ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $wdFormatPDF = 17
    $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
    $word.visible = $false
    $folderpath = "$($Folder.FullName)\*"
    $fileTypes = "*.docx","*doc"
    Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -include $fileTypes |
    foreach-object 
    {
     $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
     "Converting $path to pdf ..."
     $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
     $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
     $doc.close()
    }
    $word.Quit()
}

Get-ChildItem $Source -Filter $MoveFiles -Recurse | ForEach{
    $Path = ($_.DirectoryName + "\") -Replace [Regex]::Escape($Source), $Dest
    If(!(Test-Path $Path)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Path -Force | Out-Null
    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $Path -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to replace a file present in several sub folders, I did it as below.

```
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem File_you_want_to_be_copied.txt -Recurse)) {$target=$file.directoryname; Copy-Item -path C:\Source_Path\File_you_want_to_be_copied.txt -Destination $target}
```