# Copy specific files from a folder with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to copy lots of specific pdf files with specific names.
All the files are insame folder, I have all the file names in csv.
I made a lazy "script" which is like this (obv. not all the files in this post):

```
Copy-Item -Path 391248* -Destination <destination>
Copy-Item -Path 241044* -Destination <destination>
Copy-Item -Path 532350* -Destination <destination>
```

Does anyone have more clean solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a recursive copy script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively copy a set of files from one directory to another in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817034/recursively-copy-a-set-of-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileList  = 'C:\filelist.csv'

Get-Content -Path $fileList | ForEach-Object {

    Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination 'destination'
}
```

Comment: Please dont post code only answer, try to add some context of how this will solve the problem in question.

Comment: This is a simple one liner only

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner solution is:

```
cat "The path of csv file.csv" | % {copy -path $_ -destination "The destination"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My CSV looks like this:

```
Filename
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

This csv does not contain the file extension, the below code adds the file extension '.pdf'. You can modify it to contain anything you require.

```
$csv_location = 'path to your csv'

# 'FileName' is the name of the column inside the csv
$file_names   = ( Import-Csv $csv_location ).FileName
$destination  = 'path of files to be copied into'
$origin       = 'path of files to be copied from'

$file_names | ForEach-Object {

#   This line adds the extension '.pdf' to the filename and file path obtained from $file_names and $origin, respectively.
    $full_path = $origin + $_ + '.pdf'

#   Copy from origin to ( destination + file name + file extension )
    Copy-Item -Path ( $full_path ) -Destination $destination -Force
}
```

If your csv contains the file extension,

```
$full_path = $origin + $_
```